# Why is S-Video Out Not Working on an Acer 5720Z

Tags: 11.04, video, multiple-monitors, output

I have an Acer 5720Z which has an S-Video out port. I have been using this port primarily to view videos on my television. This worked perfectly under 9.10, 10.04 and 10.10 but under 11.04 it does not work at all.

Under 10.10 I would go into System -> Prefrences -> Monitors and it will pick up the external monitor connection and show a desktop on the TV perfectly. But after I performed an upgrade to 11.04 it would show the monitor in the Monitor preferences window but nothing on the TV. I thought something might have been mucking it up from the upgrade so I backed up my home directory on an external drive and did a clean install.

Still nothing after installing and running updates. I thought it might be something with Unity mucking it up so I logged out and logged back in under Ubuntu Classic. Still nothing showing.

I don't know if this is similar to this bug on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/723002

It's not quite the same outcome of the bug but it did involve external monitors not functioning properly.

Is there a fix for this issue?

Comment: This is not just on the Acer. There is a forum post I have added my issue to where a Dell user is having a similar issue.

Comment: Here is the post [link]http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1731751[/link]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is indeed a bug that has been registered on launchpad. It has something to do with xserver-xorg-video-intel

The bug report can be found at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/763688.